# Push notifications, Pushwoosh.com

Tags: android, eclipse, pushwoosh

Related to Android Mobile Application.
Developed with Eclipse IDE.

1. Once we create an Android App with some activities, we will get .apk after execution.
2. That .apk, uploaded in Google Play Store.
3. Later, I need to send push notifications to .apk which is installed in several mobile devices.
4. In this scenario, Pushwoosh should get only Google Project ID and then it can deliver push notifications to devices. is it not?

   - Why we need to include pushwoosh.jar? Rolling back all AndroidManifest and MainActivity?
   - Really I could not understand.
   - I dont know, I may wrong. But still, Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basics of the push notifications technology. You will need to integrate Pushwoosh SDK in order to send Push Token from the device to Pushwoosh Servers. Each and every device has its own unique push token.